# Элементы не помещаются в строку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Суть проблемы: элементы в блоке не помещаются в один ряд, последний переходит на новую строку. Уменьшение размеров не помогает.

```
        <div class="row" >

            <div class="span3" ><a href="x1"><img src="rrw/icon.png" width="100" height="100"></a><p>Металлочерепица</p></div>
            <div class="span3" ><a href="x2"><img src="rrw/icon_prof.png" width="100" height="100"></a><p>Профнастил</p></div>
            <div class="span3" ><a href="x3"><img src="rrw/icon_siding.png" width="100" height="100"></a><p>Металлический сайдинг</p></div>
            <div class="span3" ><a href="x4"><img src="rrw/icon_vodostok.png" width="100" height="100"></a><p>Водосточные системы</p></div>
            <div class="span3" ><a href="x5"><img src="rrw/icon_modul.png" width="100" height="100"></a><p>Модульные ограждения</p></div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Код где нужен код

Comment: Готово, если что-то еще нужно - скажи

Comment: Можно полный код, вместе с css'ом, ибо проблема не ясна

Comment: Нужно сделать сниппет.

Comment: Код не мой, "span3" не определен ни в одной таблице, перерыл все.

Comment: Все-равно нужен CSS, без него помочь не могу.

Comment: А если подумать над каким-нибудь абстрактным решением? Уже кучу всего перепробовал.

Comment: у вас 5 классов спан3, в одном контейнере, следует попробовать убрать классы из дочерних, используя в css first- и last-child первый и последний прибить к краям, объеденить 3 средних в еще 1 див, внутри  родительского "row", их точно так-же прибить к краям, а средний отцентрировать, тегом "center" в html
___________
ИМХО способ идиотский, но... Может сработать

Comment: Вы используете bootstrap2?

Comment: Или просто дисплей инлайн поставь :D

Answer (score 2):

Неизвестно используете ли Вы bootstrap, но в любом случаем стили можно переопределить и задать `.row { display: flex; }`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}

.span3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.custom img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.custom p {
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.custom .row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom .span3 {
  width: 20%;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .custom .span3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .custom .span3 {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .custom .span3 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="custom">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="span3">
        <a href="x1"><img src="rrw/icon.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
        <p>Металлочерепица</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <a href="x2"><img src="rrw/icon_prof.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
        <p>Профнастил</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <a href="x3"><img src="rrw/icon_siding.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
        <p>Металлический сайдинг</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <a href="x4"><img src="rrw/icon_vodostok.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
        <p>Водосточные системы</p>
      </div>
      <div class="span3">
        <a href="x5"><img src="rrw/icon_modul.png" width="100" height="100"></a>
        <p>Модульные ограждения</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Прочитайте про сетку bootstrap. Строка в ней состоит из 12 элементов. (span)3·5=12+3, вот один элемент и переносится. Уберите класс row, если вы не хотите использовать сетку.

Answer (score 0):

Задайте контейнеру с классом *row* свойство **display: flex**. В этом случае все дочерние элементы без переноса будут пытаться уместиться в контейнере по горизонтали.